# xcode with parse XML with image

Tags: xml, xcode, image, parsing

I encode an xml parser to read images on the internet but i have a problem when I compile my file on xcode
he said: "Thread 1: SIGABRT

Here is the code :

View Controller.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<NSXMLParserDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView;
    NSMutableArray *photos;
}

@end
```

viewController.m :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSXMLParser *photoParser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://davylebeaugoss.free.fr/Sans%20titre.xml"]] autorelease];

    [photoParser setDelegate:self];
    [photoParser parse];

    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[photos objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    [imgView setImage:image];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:    (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary     *)attributeDict
{
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"photo"])
    {
    [photos addObject:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"]];
}

}
@end
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: there is no question here :P just a statement that you get a crash somewhere

Comment: at which line is the error when you run ... as this is a signal, it isnt at compile time btw

Answer (score 1):

`NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[photos objectAtIndex:0]];` is your issue.

The `[photoParser parse];` is asynchronous, meaning it's not complete when the call to `objectAtIndex:0` is made.

You need to wait until the parsing is complete before you reference the array.  The method

`- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser`

will be called when the parsing is complete.  Place your call to reference the `photo` array there.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSXMLParser *photoParser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://davylebeaugoss.free.fr/Sans%20titre.xml"]] autorelease];

    [photoParser setDelegate:self];
    [photoParser parse];

}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

     NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[photos objectAtIndex:0]];
     NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
     [imgView setImage:image];
}
```

Comment: I added the changes necessary for the solution.

Comment: I did exactly what you told me but I still have the same problem ... always the same error. I referring to the "appdelegate.h"